# Is there any way to select regions of mesh with shadow and measure the surface area of the mesh?

Tags: python, mesh, lighting, shadows, measurement

I am trying to quantify shadow on different parts of a mesh at different orientations of illumination. So far all I have found is to outline the shadow manually on the mesh, separate it and use the 3d printing add-on.

I have a 3d scan of a face with a light pointing directly at it and I'd like to select the shadows, for example, on one side of the nose compared to the other and measure the surface areas against each other. [For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDYDW.jpg)

Comment: Please illustrate.. you could mean self-shadow, cast shadow, onto a flat surface, onto an arbitrary surface... anything.

Comment: Self shadow. I have a 3d scan of a face with a light pointing directly at it and I'd like to select the shadows, for example, on one side of the nose compared to the other and measure the surface areas against each other. [For example](https://imgur.com/a/VrJ5RYi)

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.